# Why will this Javascript run on individual page but not from a common file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, maskedinput

I've got an ASP.NET MVC app and I'm trying to use this [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) to mask/hint at dates. If I put this script in the `@section Scripts{}` at the bottom of the page, it functions just fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $(function($) {
                $(".datemask").mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy" });
            });
        });
</script>
```

But if I try to put it in a separate script file in the Scripts folder, so it runs on all pages, it never seems to run.  I have another script running from the Scripts folder to add the jQuery date picker to my date fields:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":input[type='datetime']").each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
```

This script runs just fine on every page (it's loaded from the _Layout.cshtml partial view).  But when I put my masking script in that file, whether part of the existing `.each` function, part of the existing `.ready` function, or in it's own `.ready` section, it never masks the textbox.

Is this something quirky about the Masked Input Plugin, or am I missing something about using JavaScript in MVC?

Comment: `:input` make no sense, just use `input`

Comment: @epascarello Couldn't say... I got that from a tutorial somewhere, but it does work (for the datepicker).  It grabs every input on a page that is bound to a datetime field.  Though even when I've put it in that same file but not that function, the mask doesn't work.

Comment: :input looks at select, textareas, butons, and inputs.... It is just checking more elements than it needs too. It is not going to fix the problem. Problem looks like you have a collision of two scripts that do not get along. Seems weird to use a date picker with a mask when the datepicker handles the format.

Comment: @epascarello I thought they might be in conflict, but they work fine together when not in the same file.  As to why both, some of the fields are recent dates (datepicker) and some are long ago (mask) but I was applying both types to both fields just to account for individual preference.

Comment: Is it the order they are added?

Comment: @epascarello Doesn't appear to be.  I've put both first and it still doesn't work when they're together.  It sounds like you think they **should** work together in the same file, so that at least tells me I'm not missing something obvious to a more experienced javascript coder and it's more likely to be something quirky between these two scripts, no?

Comment: Have you tried changing the sequence of the scripts? Calling Datepicker before Mask and vise-a-versa? Check the console for any javascript error.

Comment: step 1 would be to check the browser **developer** tools console for any "interesting" messages

Comment: OK, apparently it **was** an order thing.  I had switched the orders up within the main `$(document).ready` but hadn't made separate `$(document).ready` functions in reverse order.  I started by disabling the datepicker altogether and the mask worked in the separate file. When I reentered the datepicker at the bottom, they both worked.